# git rebase after pull request

Tags: git, rebase, pull-request

I have trouble to update a pull request.

What I did: forked a repository, cloned it locally, created a branch (pr-branch) that tracks upstream/master, committed some changes, pushed to origin, opened a pull request.

Now I need to update my pull request but changes have been made by other devs on upstream/master.

So I did :

- `git checkout -b master-updated upstream/master`
- `git pull`
- `git checkout pr-branch`
- `git rebase master-updated`

I was going to make some changes but git/source tree tells me that origin/pr-branch and pr-branch have diverged : 126 ahead and 1 behind

(I did some rebase before but never saw (or paid attention :-)) this kind of message...)

What I am supposed to do next ?

Make changes, commit then push to origin ?
Pull (but create a merge commit I guess), commit then push to origin ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Make changes, commit then push to origin ?

Yes, but the push would be a forced one:

```
git push --force
```

The goal is to replace the remote history of your `pr` branch by the local one (rebased on top of the updated upstream `master`)

> 126 ahead and 1 behind (I did some rebase before but never saw (or paid attention :-)) this kind of message...)

That seems expected after a rebase: the local and remote history are no longer the same.

Answer (score 4):

One of real beauty of git is that it's unopinionated, it let the software teams to choose their preferred workflow without imposing any particular way of working.

#### Use rebase with caution

Git `rebase` is mainly used to maintain a clean and linear project history. However, this can only be achieved by **rewriting** commit history.

Those actions are considered as **unsafe** in git, especially for published history, `reset` has a similar fame, instead, use `revert`, `checkout` or `merge` as substitution.

#### My understanding to your issue

I simulate your condition and get following snapshots of log history,

Before `git rebase`
[image]

After `git rebase`
[image]

Obviously, `git rebase` changes your old commit SHA, timestamp etc, it's rewriting your original history, but you earned a linear log graph back.

So, as mentioned by @VonC, after `git rebase` or `git rebase -i`, you usually have to use `git push -f` to **force** push your changes. As git is already safe enough to remind the devs the changes need force update, the devs themselves have to take charge of their "dangerous" actions.

#### Recommended readings

Git is well reputed for its steep learning curve, like `vi` or some other tools. It would be always good to know the basics well before using them extensively. I'm also a new user to git, i find it hard to know hundreds of git commands/aliases/tricks, but i really find this tutorial helps me grasp a better understanding of git essentials.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control

Hope it helps!